# How to pass the data in react-native's ListView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to render local state in LiestView.
I'm not familiar with ListView,¥.
it didn't work.

```
export default class Top extends Component {
  state=[{title: 'a'}, {title: 'b'}, {title: 'c'}]

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{item.key}</Text> // here
      <Category />
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this._renderItem(item)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

below is my code. it workes. How to change this code?
I need title.

```
export default class Top extends Component {
  state={
    data:[{}, {}, {}]
  };

  _renderItem = () => (
    <View>
      <Category />
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state must be an object and if you don't have a key prop, then you need to define a keyExtractor:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";

export default class Top extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [{ id: 1, title: "a" }, { id: 2, title: "b" }, { id: 3, title: "c" }]
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  // You could use the title instead of the id, but not very scalable
  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Carlos C.
However my code return Can't find variable: item.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected this line: renderItem={this._renderItem}

Answer (score 0):

First Import ListView

```
import {View, Text, ListView} from 'react-native';
```

in your component will mount create data source like this

```
 componentWillMount(){

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.yourProps);
 }
```

render the list view

```
render() {
    return (
       <View>
           <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                dataSource = {this.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
           />
       </View>     
    ); 
}
```

finally you have to let the ListView know which data and how you want to show the data in the list view. For this create a function that renders the rows of the list View

```
renderRow(yourProps) {
        return (
            <Text>{yourProps.yourData}</Text>
        );
}
```

You can style the row whatever way you want.

For more you can check this repo in gitHub: https://github.com/ishraqe/manage-user/blob/master/src/components/EmployeeList.js

Comment: ListView is deprecated and they have really bad performance: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html. FlatList should be used instead.